# How can an absolute value in a limit be negative?

Tags: limits, absolute-value

Say we have $\lim_{x\to 2}\ \frac{x-2}{|x-2|}$

Now, being that an absolute value is used, this becomes a piecewise function.

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x-2,  & \text{$x$ > 2} \\
-(x-2), & \text{$x$ < 2}
\end{cases}$

When solving the left side limit we can do:

$\lim_{x\to 2}-\ \frac{x-2}{-(x-2)}$

$\lim_{x\to 2}-\ = -1$

Why is $|x-2|$ equal to $-(x-2)$ when $x<2$ ? aren't we dealing with an absolute value so the range is always $>=0$ ?

Comment: If $x < 2$ then $x-2 < 0$ so $|x-2| = -(x-2)$

Comment: "Why is $|x-2|$ equal to $-(x-2)$ when $x<2$?"  It's because $x-2$ is then negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is $|x−2|$ equal to $-(x−2)$ when $x<2$? Aren't we dealing with an absolute value so the range is always $\geq 0$?

The range is $\geq 0$, but if $x <  2$, then  $x-2 \boxed{\color{red}{\leq}} 0$ so we need to multiply it by $-1$ to make it positive again.That is, $-(x-2) = -1 \times (x-2) \boxed{\color{blue}{\geq}} 0$ , so indeed $|x-2| = -1 \times (x-2)$.